# Java: How to get the thumbnail from a file

Tags: java, file, swing, thumbnails

In windows explorer (and linux gnome) shows for each file a thumbnail or **icon**. Like with EXEs, images, videos, txt-files, ini-files, Word documents and so much other file types. Now is my question: Is there a way to get a (preferably large) icon by file.

Something like:

```
public static BufferedImage getThumbnail(File file) {...}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like there is no AWT way of doing this.

If you're using Swing, there is a method you can use to get a Swing [`Icon`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html)...

```
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.Icon;
```

...

```
Icon ico = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
```

You can also convert that `Icon` back into an `Image` (most likely a BufferedImage, but I haven't tested it):

```
Image image = ((ImageIcon) ico).getImage();
```

There is also a class to get the icon directly, but this class is JDK dependent.  On Sun JDK's it's the `sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder` class.

If you're using SWT, things [are a bit trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975919/how-to-display-system-icon-for-a-file-in-swt).

Comment: This is what I want. Thanks, maybe you know also a way for bigger icons?

Comment: Yes, is there a way to get bigger icons?
I would like to use sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.getIcon(true), but sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder has access restriction. :-(

Comment: Is this code platform independent? It did not work for me (Linux Mint 18.3)

Comment: this works. you can recalculate the images with bufferedImage, and if you use a transparent panel, you have really nice icons , like on the desktop. works for binaries and folders. I think a "normal" image dropped onto the application is better loaded the classic way, tho ^^

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the answers above are addressing the right question.  Martijn isn't asking for the API for manipulating icon images.  He wants to know how to get to the desktop's cache of thumbnail images for items in the browsable filesystem.

I don't think there's a portable way to do this at all, but the Linux world (Gnome and KDE) adhere to the Freedesktop thumbnail standard which can be read at: http://jens.triq.net/thumbnail-spec/

There may be code, perhaps in Gtk (but probably not Java) that implements a compatibility layer for windows, but I'm not aware of it if there is.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a plattform-independent (i.e. pure java) solution, hava a look at [JavaThumbnailer](https://github.com/benjamin4ruby/java-thumbnailer). It's still beta, though, and has a limited number of supported file types.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if you will be able to get the icon but take a look at `AssociationService` that is accessible using JDIC.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/

Also this thread http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5357995

Comment: The java.sun.com link can be viewed [at archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20061030164547/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/), and there is a semi-readable version [at oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jdic-assoc-136531.html).  The forum link is not archived, unfortunately.