# How to preview any files inside a Java application?

Tags: java, windows, winapi, thumbnails, preview

I'm using a JTree to browse the content of a folder and I want that when a user click on a file, the software shows a preview of it (a screenshot of its first page).

The files are mostly Office documents and PDF.

I manage to do it for PDF file using a module downloaded from Sun, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it using any software (JARs preferably) or even the built-in Windows API.

I was thinking of converting the file to PDF then do a preview of this PDF but this isn't optimal.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got the similar problem and the best I found after couple of days of googling is following.

[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) has the same problem and resolved it with :

- An open office which runs in server mode (socket) and all the office documents are sent by alfresco to open office in order to convert them in PDF
- Those PDF are converted to .swf viewer thanks to [SWFTOOLS](http://www.swftools.org/)
- This .swf is integrated in the HTML
- For images, it uses [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to create small version of the file I suppose

Personnaly, I will try to implement it this way :

- Converting office documents to PDF thanks to open office in socket mode
- Transform the first page of the PDF into a PNG thanks to [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/open_source_pdf_viewer_download.php) library (the LGPL version)
- Diplay that PNG to the end user
- For images I would perhaps use ImageMagick too ... but for now, I'm using [Seam](http://seamframework.org/) [Image.scaleToFit](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.Final/ui/apidocs/org/jboss/seam/ui/graphicImage/Image.html#scaleToFit(int,%20int)) API

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too and stumbled over this thread. Starting with the solution from Anthony I am using Libre Office in socket mode to convert office documents directly to a PNG. Unfortunately this isn't posible from PDF's. [Here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/unoconv) is a good overview which ways are possible.

```
unoconv --connection 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2220,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext' -f png -e PageRange=1 your_file_name.extension
```

Little reference to start Libre Office in socket mode: [click me](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/sag47-492023/headless-file-conversion-using-libreoffice-as-a-service-35310/)

Answer (score 0):

I asked this a long time ago: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498506/java-howto-get-the-thumbnail-from-a-file/1498723#1498723)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I want. I want to have a thumbnail of the file, not a preview of its icon.