# How to Create a document preview in java

Tags: java, document, mouseover, preview, mousehover

I have a requirement in which i have to read a file (pdf,text,doc,docx,ppt) and display its preview on mouse hover or mouse-on event on the link of that document in java/javascript (Same as Google webpage preview or crawler ). Is it possible to achieve that requirement using java. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2950786/1285418)

Answer (score 1):

The Office docs can be converted to PDF using Microsoft Office and its capacity to save a document as a PDF. You can find multiple samples on using the Office API to print as a PDF.
For the pdf format you can use pdfbox and its feature to convert a pdf to an image and you can display the image of the first page as a preview.

Html and txt can be displayed directly or you can convert them to PDF as well.

Regards,
Mihai